# How to plot empty rectangle?

Tags: graphics

I know there is a `Rectangle[]` function, but it is always filled with some color. What I need is a rectangle, which is empty inside (only it's boundaries visible). I just need to overlay it on plotted function to indicate some of it's area.

Comment: Did you try a `Line` yet?

Comment: Was just about to start doing it, but now I see Sjoerd's answer is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `FaceForm[]` to define the polygon's filling as empty. You set the polygon's outline color with `EdgeForm[color]`

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], Rectangle[]}]
```

or slightly more complex:

```
Graphics[
   {
     EdgeForm[{Thick, Hue[Random[]]}], 
     FaceForm[], 
     Rectangle[#, # + {4, 4}]
   } & /@ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {30, 2}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness, it is hardly difficult to do this manually:

```
box[{x_, y_}, {X_, Y_}] := 
  Line[{{x, y}, {x, Y}, {X, Y}, {X, y}, {x, y}}];

Graphics[{
  {Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}]},
  {Blue, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}]},
  {Thick, box[{0, 0}, {1, 3}]}
 }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Manual control allows for customizations:

```
box2[{x_, y_}, {X_, Y_}] :=
 MapIndexed[
  {Arrowheads[Sqrt[#2]/30`], Arrow@#} &,
  Partition[{{x, y}, {x, Y}, {X, Y}, {X, y}, {x, y}}, 2, 1]
 ]

Graphics[{
  {Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 3}]},
  {Blue, Rectangle[{2, 1}, {4, 2}]},
  {Thick, box2[{0, 0}, {1, 3}]}
 }, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]