# How can I draw a rectangle with one edge not drawn?

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I want to draw a rectangle and have one of the edges not drawn

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{
{Gray,Disk[{0,0},2]},
Circle[{0,0},2+#]&/@Range[k],
EdgeForm[{Thin}], White,
Rectangle[{-2-k,2+k},{0,2+k-1}]
}],{k,2,10,1}]
```

[image]

The right edge in this case to have a visual effect of a wire unwinding, like this:

[image]

Comment: I would build my own replacement for `Rectangle` using an edgeless `Rectangle` and `Line` as needed, e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10498/121

Comment: I wanted to see some elegant solution to not draw the edge, but thanks - overlaping Rectangle with a Line worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks OK to me. Will it work for you?

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    {{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]},
     AbsoluteThickness[2], Circle[{0, 0}, 2 + #] & /@ Range[k],
     White, EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[2], Black}], 
       Polygon[{{0, 2 + k}, {-2 - k, 2 + k}, {-2 - k, 2 + k - 1}, {0, 2 + k - 1}}],
    {AbsoluteThickness[4], Line[{{0, 2 + k}, {0, 2 + k - 1}}]},
    Black, 
      Line[{{-.02 k, 2 + k}, {.02 k, 2 + k}}], 
      Line[{{-.02 k, 2 + k - 1}, {.02 k, 2 + k - 1}}]}],
  {k, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

**Using `MeshPrimitives`:**

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{
   {Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}
   , Thick, Circle[{0, 0}, 2 + #] & /@ Range[k]
   , {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[None], #
      , Thick, MeshPrimitives[#, 1][[{1, 3, 4}]]} &@
    Rectangle[{-2 - k, 2 + k}, {0, 2 + k - 1}]
   }]
 , {k, 2, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   Graphics[{{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 2]}, 
     Circle[{0, 0}, 2 + #] & /@ Range[k], EdgeForm[{Thin}], White, 
     Rectangle[{-2 - k, 2 + k}, {0, 2 + k - 1}]}],
   Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[White], 
     Rectangle[{-0.001, 2 + k}, {0.001, 2 + k - 1}]}]
   }], {k, 2, 10, 1}]
```

with the effect as follows:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: This produces an image of unacceptable quality as the rectangle with offset also "wipes" the cirle edges a bit. I tried overlapping a white rectangle with Line[] but that is also not what I wanted to have to further manipulate. Isn't there a "proper" way to just not draw an edge?

Comment: @grandrew "Isn't there a "proper" way to just not draw an edge?"  Not that I know. You may also add points to my solution on top of the rectangle to cover the edges. Or you may alternatively add a white line on top of your rectangle and play with its thickness and length to cover the edge, but this is in fact goes into a direction that  Mr. Wizard proposed.  You may also add a rectangle like you did, but not only fix its bulk to be white, but also its edges: `EdgeForm[White]`, and then on top of it you may draw a line covering those three edges of the rectangle that you need.